# Continuity necessary for derivative of monotone function theorem

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, monotone-functions

Why does $f$ need to be continuous in this theorem? Continuity is already implied by differentiability for $(a,b)$, right? Why do we bother with a stronger prerequisite?

> Let $f$ be a real function which is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$.
>
> - If $\forall x \in (a,b): f'(x) \ge 0$, then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$.
> - If $\forall x \in (a,b): f'(x) \gt 0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.
> - If $\forall x \in (a,b): f'(x) \le 0$, then $f$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$.
> - If $\forall x \in (a,b): f'(x) \lt 0$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[a,b]$

Comment: Continuity is needed on the entire interval, including $a, b$, from differentiability you have it only on the open interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider e.g. the function

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0&, 0 \leq x < 1\\ -1&, x = 1\end{cases}$$

on the interval $[0,1]$. Then you have $f'(x) \geq 0$ on $(0,1)$, but still $f$ is not increasing on $[0,1]$ because $f(1) < f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1)$. The problem is that $f$ is not continuous at the endpoint $x = 1$. Similar counterexamples work for the other three points of the theorem.

Comment: Thanks! But if I’m only interested in $(a,b)$ then I don’t need the continuity?

Comment: Yes! Continuity at the endpoints is only important if you want to include the monotonicity at the endpoints.